# How to modularize a dynamic ggvis chart in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, ggvis

My app has a few charts, and I would like to draw them in a sperate script in order to have a cleaner `server.R` which then contains only the `bind_shiny` calls.

Also, because I would like to recycle some of the building blocks of my charts, I would like to split the script to draw the charts in smaller parts of code.

Right know, I have a **charts.R** file like this:

```
chart1 <- reactive({
  cars %>% 
    ggvis(~speed) 

})

chart2 <- reactive({
  chart1 %>% layer_bars() 
})
```

The reactivity is not needed of course, but it will in my original application.

Then, I would like to call the chart on **server.R** this way:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggvis)
source("charts.R")
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

chart2 %>% 
  bind_shiny("test1", "test1_ui")
})
```

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(ggvis)
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  fluidRow(titlePanel("My app")),

    fluidRow(
          column(12,
                 tags$h1("hello"),
                 ggvisOutput('test1')
                 )
    )
   )
  )
```

I have noticed everything works in charts.R when I put everything in one object, but it does not if I split the function that draws the chart in multiple pieces. However, something like this works

```
> a <-  cars %>% 
+   ggvis(~speed)
> a
Guessing layer_histograms()
Guessing width = 0.5 # range / 42
> a %>% layer_bars()
```

Anybody could explain how to fix the issue and why my two-steps approach works in R but not in Shiny?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your problem is that you can't see the plot, that is because in your second `recative` statement, you need to refer to `chart1` as `chart1()`. In other words, change your `charts.R` to

**Charts.R**

```
chart1 <- reactive({
            cars %>% 
              ggvis(~speed)
 })

chart2 <- reactive({
           chart1() %>% layer_bars()
 })
```

If you want to learn more about reactivity, please check out [this](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/reactivity-overview.html) link.